# Ruby/Rails - dynamically specify connection properties for class

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

Our app receives data from various feeds.

One feed is provided to us in the form of a database.  Therefore we have this database living in the same MySQL server instance as our app database.  Further updates to this feed database are provided as a delta and must be processed into the complete feed database.

So, I have:

- app_db
- feed_db
- feed_delta_db

`feed_db` and `feed_delta_db` have the same structure (tables, columns etc).

Sometimes I need to access `feed_db` and sometimes I need to access `feed_delta_db`.

Before I started receiving the delta, I accessed `feed_db` like this:

```
module Feed
  module Db
    module InstanceMethods
      def something
        puts 'pffffft'
      end
    end

    def self.included(receiver)
      receiver.send :include, InstanceMethods
      receiver.instance_eval {
        establish_connection(
          {
            :adapter => "mysql2",
            :database => "feed_db",
            :username => "mysql_user",
            :password => nil,
            :host => "localhost"
          }
        )
      }
    end
  end

  class FeedModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Db
    self.abstract_class = true
  end

  class Sometable < FeedModel
    set_table_name "sometable"
    belongs_to :someothertable, :foreign_key => "SomeothertableID", :primary_key => "id"

    def name
      "#{field1} #{field2}"
    end
  end
end
```

Now I could duplicate all this code for `feed_delta_db`, and the only thing I'd have to change is the database specified in the connection details.

But that isn't DRY, is it?

The result would be what I want though.  I'd be able to access the tables in the separate databases like so:
`Feed::Sometable` and `FeedDelta::Sometable`

How can I separate my class definitions to their own file and include/require/whatever them into separate modules (or classes) so I can access either db at will?

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would define a generic parent class and then switch the db in the child class

```
class GenericParent < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end

class Feed < GenericParent
  establish_connection :feed_db
end

class FeedDelta < GenericParent
  establish_connection :feed_delta_db
end

# config/database.yml
development:
  ...

feed_db:
  ...

feed_delta_db:
  ...
```

It would be wise to honor different environments. So your `establish_connection` may look more like:

```
class Feed < GenericParent
  establish_connection :"feed_#{Rails.env}"
end
```

Which will allow you to have a feed_development, feed_staging, feed_production, etc sections in your database.yml

Comment: Does this help me in DRYing up my class definitions?  e.g. I'd still have to define `class Sometable` twice right?  Once inheriting from `Feed` and once inheriting from `FeedDelta`

Comment: Do you treat them as separate models (distinct functionality and/or responsibility) or are you just trying to manage two connections to different databases?

Comment: The latter.  The classes are identical in functionality, associations, methods, database table structures, etc. (and should remain that way).  They just need to connect to two different databases (which have different data sets).

Comment: If you are using them one at a time, I would call `establish_connection` externally and pass in whatever connection string you wish to use (so you just have one implementation of your classes). If you need to use both connections at the same time, I would put the functionality in the `GenericParent` and do a shallow extension that just calls `establish_connection` (as in my example above).